# Commit Hook Failure

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I'm trying to implement some hooks, both pre and post fail however.  I get the same error message for both when I try to commit:

```
'*-commit' hook failed (did not exit cleanly: apr_exit_why_e was 2, exitcode was
-1073741515).   with no output.
```

Exitcode -1073741515 looks to be an odd one, and a quick bit of google-fu got me this:

> Treated as a hex DWORD, the error code you are seeing is 0xC0000135.
>
> That is Sev=11, C=0, R=0, Facility=0, Code=0x0135.
>
> The value 0xC0000135 can be found in NtStatus.h with the following definition

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND
//
// MessageText:
//
//  {Unable To Locate Component}
//  This application has failed to start because %hs was not found.
// Re-installing the application may fix this problem.
//
#define STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND             ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000135L)
```

Ok, dll not found, shouldn't be too difficult right?  I have a VM with svn on it that's being peaceful with these hooks.  So I run Filemon.exe and Depends.exe on both machines.

I'm still slogging through the filemon logs for both servers, and depends isn't giving me any unique problems with any executable that I can think of being hit by a Commit Hook.

I decided to take a quick peek in the event logs, and Oh Boy!

> 'pre-commit' hook failed (did not exit cleanly: apr_exit_why_e was 2, exitcode was -1073741515).   with no output.  [409, #165001]

Extra smidgens of information, this [409, #165001] is all over google, but I'm not really picking up anything helpful.

The hook is explicitly calling an executable with three parameters.

> C:\SubversionNotify\SubversionNotify.exe %1 %2 -pre

I've even tried to use variables as well.

```
SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2
C:\SubversionNotify\SubversionNotify.exe %REPOS% %REV% -pre
```

Looking in the filemon logs shows me that it never makes it to SubversionNotify.exe

It's getting to the point where I can't really spend much more time trying to implement this, help me SO, you're my only hope.

Server Specs:

> Windows XP, running VisualSVN Server, latest release.

Edit:
It seems as though SubversionNotify is throwing the exception, back to Depends.exe to check to see what dll is failing.

Error is as follows:

> The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135).

That 0xC0000135 was seen earlier, dll hunt ahoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd thought I'd share the Solution here, as I got a great laugh out of it.

The SubversionNotify was written in .NET.
The Server did not have the .NET Framework installed.
The VM did.

I am wearing a dunce cap now.

Answer (score 3):

Normally the problem with commit hooks is that there is ABSOLUTELY no environment (thus no path), so all references have to be painfully explicit. I usually end up making a small batch file that changes directory to the proper directory and executes the command.

Edit:

TRY CHANGING DIRECTORY TO C:\SubversionNotify

Maybe you are missing some runtime dll that is required to run the program.
Remember: There is NO path. You can simulate this by setting path to NOTHING in a command line window. 
    set PATH=.

Verify that simple commands like notepad do not work. Does your exe work then? Find out where the missing dlls are and build a path at the start of the batch file.

Comment: The hook is explicitly calling an executable with three parameters.

C:\SubversionNotify\SubversionNotify.exe %1 %2 -pre

The question has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: Changing directory to C::\SubversionNotify nets me:
'Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: SubversionNotify is in fact throwing the exception, missing some dll, just need to find out what one.  Luckily I have a VM that seems to work with SubversionNotify.  Compare and contrast time.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your answer.  If you didn't I would have spent a lot more time trying to run this down and feeling even more stupid than I do now.  Just blew out a box and did an install of VisualSVN and SubversionNotify and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.